# Increase Allowance of Smart Contract to Transfer a Users ERC20 Tokens

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x

First, let me apologize because I've seen this question asked multiple times but I can't figure it out still.

```
  function setAllowance(address tokenAddr, uint256 amount) external payable {
    IERC20(tokenAddr).safeIncreaseAllowance(address(this), amount * 10**18);
  }

  function getAllowance(address tokenAddr) external view returns (uint256) {
    return IERC20(tokenAddr).allowance(msg.sender, address(this)) / 10**18;
  }
```

This is my function in solidity. I'm calling it from **React** so within this function the caller/msg.sender is my **external metamask wallet address**. I want my contract to be able to send tokens on behalf of the external metamask wallet. However, the allowance does not increase. I believe my setAllowance is wrong, but it doesn't have a **"owner"** & **"spender" parameter**, **only "spender"** which is my contract `(ie. address(this))`.

So how do I know who the spender is getting the allowance from, because I want it to be the external metamask wallet, but clearly that is not happening and it's getting an allowance from something else.

I want to add in that I swapped address(this) and msg.sender, but I don't want my external wallet to have an allowance from the contract, I need it the other way around. (though in this case, the allowance did increase).

Edit 1:
Im using  import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol"
and the function:

```
    function safeIncreaseAllowance(
        IERC20 token,
        address spender,
        uint256 value
    ) internal {
        uint256 newAllowance = token.allowance(address(this), spender) + value;
        _callOptionalReturn(token, abi.encodeWithSelector(token.approve.selector, spender, newAllowance));
    }
```

Edit 2: Testing it on **Mumbai network (Polygon testnet)**

**Faucet:** https://faucet.polygon.technology/

Using: Test ERC20 Plasma from this faucet on Mumbai

**Testing Token**: https://polygonscan.com/token/0xfe4F5145f6e09952a5ba9e956ED0C25e3Fa4c7F1

Comment: Hi, which interface are you implementing? 
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol
is it this one?
Cannot find any IERC20 that implements `safeIncreaseAllowance()`

Comment: @StanislavSvědiroh. I can replace ``safeIncreaseAllowance`` with ``approve`` from that and still get the same issue. for the function you mentioned, got it from this: import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";

Comment: But this interface doesn't even have `safeIncreaseAllowance()` method. Using this you need to call `approve(address spender, uint256 amount)` to be able to set allowance.

Comment: Sorry updated comment, misread

Comment: What does your token implementation inherit from?

Comment: Its not my token, I'm currently trying to implement it using USDT.

Comment: import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/utils/SafeERC20.sol";

using SafeERC20 for IERC20;

Comment: @sarmanaulakh The problem is that you are calling the token from a contract, the call changes `msg.sender` to the contract address. A contract cannot act on behalf of another account. If you want to increase the allowance for a user the user itself has to call the token function approve or increaseAllowance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Ismael♦ for the clue, helped me go in the right direction. Don't think I can upvote the comment cause I'm a new user (only getting flag option).

**Solution:**

1. Get Token ABI from etherscan
2. initialize token contract

```
 new ethers.Contract(tokenAddress, tokenAbi, signer)
```

3. call approve on token contract (giving address of ur deployed contract)
   **THEN**
4. proceed to transfer tokens from their wallet using your own contract

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about this contract?

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x3b00ef435fa4fcff5c209a37d1f3dcff37c705ad#code

If so, I would personally just create my own interface, because the USDT implementation is kinda wild:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

interface IERC20 {
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint256);

    function approve(address spender, uint256 value) external returns (bool);

    function allowance(address owner, address spender)
        external
        view
        returns (uint256);

    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 addedValue)
        external
        returns (bool);

    function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint256 subtractedValue)
        external
        returns (bool);
}
```

You can even delete the `approve()` function if you won't be using it.

Note that this will **NOT** work the same way on mainnet, because there's a completely different implementation of an older ERC20 version.

Comment: I'm on mumbai testnet, sorry think my edit on the question happened while u wrote out this answer. 

Faucet: https://faucet.polygon.technology/
Using: Test ERC20 Plasma from this faucet on Mumbai
Token: https://polygonscan.com/token/0xfe4F5145f6e09952a5ba9e956ED0C25e3Fa4c7F1

Lets ignore USDT for now, just a generic ERC20 token because I want to be able to pass any erc20 token with 18 decimals. 

Also, how does making your own interface even work? Don't you need to implement it? Will ``IERC20(tokenArr)`` still work?

Comment: Making your own interface works the same way as importing it from github. After all, import statement is just a way to tell the compiler to copy the whole referrenced code to that exact line.

Comment: Connected to mumbai and claimed those Test ERC20 tokens. The correct contract for it is: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/token/0x2d7882beDcbfDDce29Ba99965dd3cdF7fcB10A1e. Other than that I was only able to get my balance from solidity, they seem to only have approve function but I wasn't been able to get it working. This is their implementation for TypeScript and their docs
https://github.com/maticnetwork/maticjs-plasma/blob/main/src/erc20.ts
https://docs.polygon.technology/docs/develop/ethereum-polygon/plasma/erc20
Sorry, I don't know much about the inner workings of polygon.